# How to offset poor undergraduate performance in core classes?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, grades

I recently did not do so well in a couple undergraduate core classes, what are my options to make up for this on a grad school application?

Comment: Your question is very long and missed a few important points. What were the classes you failed the 3rd semester(this one)? Besides building the student organization, is there any other reason you failed the classes?

Comment: I will edit it to include the course names.

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything else that might need to be added in for clarity.

Comment: There are many mathematics professors on this site, I'll let them answer your question. But, I'll have an opinion here. You failed Galois Theory because you did not grasp the basics of groups/rings/fields well. How do you study graduate level Algebra without enough knowledge about groups/rings/fields? That is, even if you get in one of the good graduate schools in Math?

Comment: As answered in http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38237/19607 doing well in a master's program is a good way to offset poor undergrad performance.

Comment: You seem to be aiming for more success by retaking at the graduate level the courses you failed. Isn't that the kind of thinking that got you into trouble in the first place?

Comment: In my opinion what led me to fail was lack of effort and preparation. My plan is to spend all summer working through a couple of books to learn what I was supposed to learn in order to be successful. And it is possible to take graduate courses at my school, so I would not need to go elsewhere to take them.

Comment: @aparente001 If you are being sarcastic regarding the bipolar disorder comment, point taken. If not, I'm not exactly sure how you would get that from this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer the first question here.

If the course you're skipping is a "mandatory" course in your major, then taking advanced courses to make up for the earlier failures is not sufficient unless you get the necessary approvals to do so. (Usually there is some sort of departmental advisor whom you can petition.) However, I should mention that given your past record, it is quite likely that such a request will be denied.